# How to set URL so it loads the user page

Tags: php, laravel

In route.php I have the following...

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
    'as' => 'profile-user',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));
```

In ProfileController I have the following...

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController {
    public function user($username) {
        $user = User::where('username', '=', $username);

        if($user->count()) { // if the corresponding user exists...
            $user = $user->first();

            return View::make('profile.user')
                    ->with('user', $user);
        }

        return App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

In navigation.blade.php I have the following...

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile-user') }}">User Profile</a></li>
```

How can I make it so that navigation.blade.php will provide the correct link to the user profile? At the moment the link looks like the following in html...

```
http://website.dev/user/%7Busername%7D
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
http://website.dev/user/currentlyLoggedInUserName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I'll leave the answer here for other people.

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile-user', Auth::user()->username) }}">User Profile</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `HTML::link`. Example:

```
{{ HTML::link('/user/<?=$user_name?>', 'User Profile')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<li><a href="@{{ URL::route('profile-user') }}">User Profile</a></li>
```

because it is a Laravel PHP function url() that must resolve first, and the result is passed to Handlebars.